# Turn Off GPS Updates in Genymotion GPS Widget

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion, genymotion-gps

Just started using Genymotion because I've become sick of the Android emulators.

The GPS widget is really useful to me however the location broadcasts do not seem to be turning off when I turn the switch in the widget panel off.

Does anyone else know how to fix it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Genymotion GPS feature isn't implemented such that locations are broadcast like they are with a mock location provider.  Instead, they are updated when the widget is turned on, and every time you move the map pin.  When you turn the widget off, they're not set anymore, but the last setting will persist as the last known location. You can see this behavior by looking at the logcat.

Comment: When using it, I can turn on the widget and a location is provided from then on consistently. What I would expect to happen is when i turn off the widget, locations stop being broadcast however they don't

Comment: Agreed, I just don't think they implemented it that way, so there's really nothing to fix about it. I ended up using a mock location provider for what I was doing, partially because of this undesirable behavior.